# How do I reference the position of an element in a list for and use that position to reference element in another list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, python-pptx

I have a Pandas Dataframe with multiple column. For example:

```
    Data.csv
| ID       | Name     | Initial Date| Final Date | Irrelevant Column | 
| 1        | Orange   | 02/23/23    | 03/01/23   | Data              |
| 2        | Apple    | 01/10/23    | 01/12/23   | Different Data    |
```

The data is read and converted into a DataFrame

```
data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
#Proccess data (drop duplicate here)
```

I converted these columns into a list

```
data_ID = data['ID].tolist()
data_Name = data['Name'].tolist()
data_Initial_Date =data['Initial Date'].tolist()
data_Final_Date = data['Final Date'].tolist()
```

Now I want to put these information into multiple PowerPoints using Python-pptx. I want each PowerPoint to contain one row of information, but exclude the 'Irrelevant Column' column

```
import pptx
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation('Template.pptx') #Template.pptx is a template presentation with placeholders so I can just replace the text/image
slide = prs.slides[0]
ID = slide.placeholders[1]
Name = slide.placeholders[2]
Initial_Date = slide.placeholders[3]
Final_Date = slide.placeholders[4]

#Now replacing text in the placeholders
for x in data_ID:
   ID.text = x
for z in data_Initial_Date:
    Initial_Date.text = z
for i in data_Final_Date:
    Final_Date.text = i
for y in data_Name:
    Name.text = y
    prs.save(y+'.pptx)
# Save the PowerPoint with name from the Name column
```

The text for the Name placeholder and the title of the PowerPoint would be correct, but the ID, Initial Date, and Final Date would just be from the first row.

How do I get it so that each PowerPoint would contain the information from a specific row?

```
data = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
#Proccess data (drop duplicate here)

data_ID = data['ID].tolist()
data_Name = data['Name'].tolist()
data_Initial_Date =data['Initial Date'].tolist()
data_Final_Date = data['Final Date'].tolist()

import pptx
from pptx import Presentation
prs = Presentation('Template.pptx') #Template.pptx is a template presentation with placeholders so I can just replace the text/image
slide = prs.slides[0]
ID = slide.placeholders[1]
Name = slide.placeholders[2]
Initial_Date = slide.placeholders[3]
Final_Date = slide.placeholders[4]

#Now replacing text in the placeholders
for x in data_ID:
   ID.text = x
for z in data_Initial_Date:
    Initial_Date.text = z
for i in data_Final_Date:
    Final_Date.text = i
for y in data_Name:
    Name.text = y
    prs.save(y+'.pptx)
# Save the PowerPoint with name from the Name column
```

Comment: Note the missing quote in the first line of m your first snippet of code. Therefore I assume that wasn't copied from your original code.

Comment: Yeah, I wrote this code up as an example. This was not copied from the original code